# Java is not launching GZIP command when using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, processbuilder

I definitely have `GZIP` installed on the boxes where I am trying this out. But when I run this in Java, I don't see the zipped file being created. The file I am dealing with is a really large file and I would rather not read it into memory. The following is the code, I have written for this purpose. My hunch is that it has something to do with Redirects.

```
try {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("gzip", "-9", "<", filename, ">", zippedFilename);
    builder.start();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You might try `ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", "gzip -9 < " + filename + " > " + zippedFilename);`

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: I assume you don't have a file called `<`  I suggest you print out the errors this program produces to work out why it fails.

Comment: Some more background on KevinO's answer: the `<` and `>` file redirects are not a feature of `gzip`. They are done by the shell (`/bin/sh`) and will not work if you start `gzip` directly.

Comment: KevinO’s suggestion will not work if the file path has spaces or any characters considered special by the shell.  Use ProcessBuilder’s redirection instead.  (And by the way, [Java can do gzip compression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html), so you don’t really need an external process at all.)

Comment: More generally: building a command line using `/bin/sh` like @KevinO shows is a **security hazard**! This is the shell equivalent of a SQL injection vulnerability. If you must build command lines using strings, make sure to be paranoid about quoting everything. Better yet, don't do that at all, and manage the pipes into and out of a subprocess directly rather than launching a whole separate shell process to do it for you.

Comment: @VGR, you are of course correct, and I thought about pointing out the redirection stuff, but with a `printStackTrace()` this didn't seem like production level code, and for a one-off in line with the original question, it seemed a bit better. But thank you for raising the important caveats.

Answer (score 2):

First, it’s worth noting that you can make this easier by avoiding an external process and using Java to do the compression:

```
Path input = Paths.get(filename);
Path zipped = Paths.get(zippedFilename);

try (OutputStream out = new GZIPOutputStream(
    new BufferedOutputStream(
        Files.newOutputStream(zipped)))) {

    Files.copy(input, out);
}
```

This has the additional advantage of being fully multi-platform.  No need to require /usr/bin/gzip, no need to require Unix tools on Windows.  It won’t implement the `-9` option, but I would check how much additional compression one actually gets with that option, and weigh whether it’s worth having a less portable program.

For other commands (or if `-9` is critically important), a ProcessBuilder command cannot do redirection of input and output with `<` and `>`, for the same reason a C program would not be able to accomplish redirection with a call like:

```
/* Does not work. */
execl("/usr/bin/gzip", "gzip", "-9", "<", filename, ">", zippedFilename, (char *)NULL);
```

When you run a command in a shell (like bash), the shell intercepts `<` and `>`, strips them and their subsequent arguments from the command, and invokes the actual program without them.  Thus, typing this:

```
gzip -9 < filename > filename.gz
```

actually causes the shell to run `gzip` with just one argument:  `-9`.  The shell then reads from `filename` and passes it to the standard input descriptor of the gzip program’s process.  Similarly, the shell captures the standard output from that same gzip program invocation, and writes it to `filename.gz`.

While this is going on, the gzip process has no idea where its input came from, or where its output is going.  It is just reading from its own standard input and writing to its standard output.

When you invoke a program directly, you are bypassing the shell, so there is no special handling of `<` and `>`.  This means that your current ProcessBuilder command is the equivalent of this Unix command:

```
gzip -9 '<' filename '>' filename.gz
```

which means you are invoking gzip with one option and four file arguments, which cause gzip to first look for a file whose name is one character long, a file literally named `<`, then write a compressed version of it to `<.gz`.  It will then do the same with a file named `filename`, then a file named `>`, then a file named `filename.gz`.

So, as you can see, Unix commands know nothing about redirection.  The `<` and `>` characters cannot be passed to them directly.

However, you can simulate redirection using ProcessBuilder:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("gzip", "-9");
builder.inheritIO();
builder.redirectInput(new File(filename));
builder.redirectOutput(new File(zippedFilename));

Process process = builder.start();
```

The call to inheritIO() will cause the external process’s standard error (that is, any error messages) to appear on the Java program’s standard error.  Without that, you would have no indication of why the program failed.  (It would do the same with standard input and standard output, if we hadn’t redirected them.)